# PHP running before HTML

Tags: php

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219192/unable-to-resolve-warning-and-notice) I've been building out my website, but I ran into an issue when I add the HTML form below the PHP code, (which I previously build out as a separate file), when I include the HTML code below the PHP code, the PHP code is taking priority over the HTML code, by that I mean the line "die ('Please complete the registration form!');" is being called.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: That's because you don't check if your form was __really__ submitted.

Comment: You have to remember, that the page when first loaded has not been submitted and therefore data will not exists in the form fields. So if you want help please show us **all** the page code, or at least a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there's hardly any php here. As for your *"y that I mean the line "die ('Please complete the registration form!');" is being called."* - where's that?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner : this is a follow on question as mentioned in my post, I didn't want to get in trouble for re-posting the same code, the previous post is linked in the first post.

Comment: PHP stands for "hypertext preprocessor". It's supposed to run before HTML. Any HTML/JS/CSS in a PHP script does nothing on the server side and is simply sent to the browser for execution. If you say `die()` in PHP, that exits the script on the server and the rest of your code and markdown is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code from your previous question is still relevant. *If you made mods you will have to check this as I didn't go through answers in case you didn't do exactly as they suggested*

You must always do some test to check that the form was actually submitted. Remember the first time a page loads, from click on a link or you entering the  URL directly into the browser, the form has not been submitted and therefore NONE of the form fields will be populated in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays for you to make use of.

Now here I am using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` which will not be set if you just ran the page, but will contain either `POST` or `GET` if the form submit button was actually presses. Once you know that you can proceed with checking all the fields have been properly entered and do any sanitization that may be required upon those fields.

```
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Change this to your connection info.
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = '';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = '';

// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


// before doing anything with the posted field value
// check to see if the form was actually posted
// or is this the first time the page has been laoded


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    // Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
    if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {
        // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
        die ('Please complete the registration form!');
    }

    // Also check if the submitted values are empty
    if ( empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
        // One or more values are empty...
        die ('Please complete the registration form!');
    }
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        die ('Email is not valid!');
    }
    if (preg_match('^[0-9A-Za-z_]+$^', username) == 0) {
        die ('Invalid username!');
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
        die ('Password must be between 5 and 20 characters long.');
    }
    // We need to check if the account with that username exists
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
        // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // Username already exists
            echo 'Username exists, please choose another!';
        } else {
            // Username doesnt exists, insert new account
            if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT), $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo 'You have successfully registered, you can now login!';
            } else {
                echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
    }

// HTML CODE TO FOLLOW after the `?>`
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post, I really appreciate it, your reply helps clear up where I went wrong and I really appreciate it, the PHP could of been wrapped inside the if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST').

Comment: Well it need to be valid HTML with all the '<html>` and `<head>` and `<body>` tags etc etc

Comment: Yeah, my bad, thanks, it's working, much appreciated.